# Как достать данные из одного массива по данным из другого массива vue

Tags: vue.js

Есть два массива-

```
name_social = [
  'name' => 'VK'
];

social = [
   'VK' => 'link vk'
];
```

Мне нужно перебрать весь массив `name_social` и в цикле достать значения из массива `social`

Как я пробовал

```
<div v-for="soc in name_social">
  {{social.+soc.name}}<!-- Должно получиться так social.VK-->
</div>
```

Выдает ошибку `- invalid expression: Undexpected token + in (social.+soc.name)
 Raw expression: {{social.soc.name}}`

Думал создать переменную и в нее внести `soc.name`, а потом эту переменную подставить к `social`. Но так тоже не работает, пишет что такого нет в массиве

Также попробовал сделать без `+`

```
<div v-for="soc in name_social">
  {{social.soc.name}}<!-- Должно получиться так social.VK-->
</div>
```

Выдает ошибку 'app.js:37809 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'

Comment: и какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @Дмытрык Обновил вопрос, если я правлеьно понял

Comment: так должно работать – `{{ social[soc.name] }}`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Да, все работает, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div v-for="soc in name_social">
  {{social[soc.name]}}
</div>
// Либо так
<div v-for="(soc, i) in name_social">
  {{social[i].name}}
</div>
```